# Audio processing - where would I start in terms of books and learning

Tags: objective-c, audio, resources

I've only just started learning Objective-C but am interested in audio processing and editing software and would like to know where to find information on where to start.

It's early days yet so I'm just looking for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

book: 'The Computer Music Tutorial' by Curtis Roads.

is a very good place to start.

Comment: Just had a look for the book - it seems to be right on the money!
Thanks,
Spencer.

Answer (score 2):

You need signal processing background. So a discrete-time signal processing book such as oppenheim will do.

It's not going to be a walk in the park if you aren't good at math.

Comment: My maths is terrible! However, I can learn!
Thanks for the tip!
Spencer.